# problems im facing while using react router and react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

I just discovered the `react-router` and I decided to try it out
but I keep having this error and my code refused to work.

This is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"/>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="..//src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my index.js file

```
import React  from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import css from './App.css'

function Web(){
  return(
    <div>
      <App/>
    </div>
  )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Web/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

This is my app.js file

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Router, Routes} from 'react-router-dom'
import './App.css';
import react from 'react'
import  ReactDOM  from 'react';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<div>fhhthrtytt</div>}/>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

This is the error I'm getting in the console

```
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
 See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting ?

Comment: You forgot to post the error.

Comment: i updated it pls check it out

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's the extraneous `script` tag trying to run your `index.js` file. It doesn't appear to be necessary here.

```
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="..//src/index.js"></script> // <-- remove this
</body>
```

Should be:

```
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: it did not work i got the same error

Comment: @OkormoruPraise Interesting. Think you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this warning that we could inspect live?